# Python - When to create a Class and when to create a Function

Tags: python, function, class, oop

Right, so I'm trying to create a Contacts application using Python OOP. I'm fairly new to OOP and still trying to get my head around the concepts.

I understand that a Class is a blueprint for all objects. I like to think of a Class as an entity and each Object is a record of that entity. I am from a Database background so that's why I interpret it like this, feel free to correct me.

Anyways, in the Contacts app I'm making I've created the Class `Contacts` as outlined below:

```
 class Contacts():
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, address, groupType,
                 telephone, mobile, email, photoField):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = address
        self.groupType = groupType
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.email = email
        self.photoField = photoField

    def showDetails(self):
        print("First Name:\t", self.firstName)
        print("Last Name:\t", self.lastName)
        print("Address:\t", self.address)
        print("Telephone:\t", self.telephone)
        print("Mobile:\t", self.mobile)
        print("Email:\t", self.email)
```

Now, if I want to *add* contacts through the Contacts class into the list I'm using to store each contact object, do I have to create an `AddContacts` class, or do I create a function instead? I don't know if I'm putting my question across well enough for you to understand what I mean?

What I guess I'm trying to say is that adding contacts is a process and if you look at it from a database point of view you wouldn't create a table called "tbl_AddContacts" since you would do that via a query or a stored procedure, so in my view I would define adding contacts being a function. But asking my colleague who does C# programming he says that adding contacts should be defined by a Class.

This is a confusing concept for me, especially since I don't understand how I would link the `AddContacts` class with the `Contacts` class, or even how to define an `AddContacts` class in the first place!.

Here is the function I defined for adding contacts:

```
def addContacts():
    firstName = input("First Name: ")
    lastName = input("Last Name: ")
    address = input("Address: ")
    telephone = input("Telephone: ")
    mobile = input("Mobile: ")
    email = input("Email: ")
    print("\n")

    contact = Contacts(firstName, lastName, address, None, telephone, mobile, email, None)

    contactsList.append(contact)

    pickle.dump(contactsList, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

Please help me out, since I will turning this into a GUI application (uni assignment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a contact is doing something, rather than being something, so it would make sense as a method/function rather than a class. I would suggest that your functionality should actually be in two separate places.

Creating a new contact from user input should be a *class method* of `Contact`:

```
class Contact(object):

    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        firstName = input("First Name: ")
        lastName = input("Last Name: ")
        address = input("Address: ")
        telephone = input("Telephone: ")
        mobile = input("Mobile: ")
        email = input("Email: ")
        return cls(firstName, lastName, address, None, 
                   telephone, mobile, email, None)
```

Adding a new contact to the list of contacts should either be:

1. An *instance method* of the e.g. `AddressBook` or `ContactList` class (or whatever you have holding the contact list); or
2. A separate *function* if you don't have a class to hold the `Contact` instances.

For example:

```
class AddressBook(object):

    ...

    def add_contact(self, contact=None):
        if contact is None:
            contact = Contact.from_input()
        self.contacts.append(contact)
```

Now your UI can create a `Contact` and pass it straight to `address_book.add_contact()`.

Comment: Cheers for the help. I'm struggling to actually pass through my contact object through the `add_contact` construct, but I'll figure it out eventually.

Answer (score 3):

First, your `Contacts` class is more appropriately called `Contact`, since it only represents a single contact. Your `addContacts` options can either be a standalone function, or you could make it part of a `ContactList` class, which manages your list of `Contact` objects.

```
class ContactList():
    def __int__(self):
        self.contact_list = []

    def addContact(firstName, lastName, address, telephone, mobile, email):
        contact = Contact(firstName, lastName, address, None, telephone, mobile, email, None)
        self.contact_list.append(contact)
        pickle.dump(contact_list, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

I would recommend separating the UI interaction piece (all the `input()` calls) from your function/method, because as you said, eventually this is going to become a GUI app. You should keep the code that's actually getting input from the user separated so you can change it later without having to change any part of `Contact` or `ContactList`.